# Google app maker: How to list existent groups?

Tags: google-app-maker

I've created a new google app through their app maker interface. I've added "Google Admin Directory API" as a service and "Directory" as a data source. I created a page that will hold 2 tables, one that list all users within my domain (this is already working) and another table that lists all of the groups within my domain (not working). How can I achieve this? Can this be done through their widgets or do I have to create a script and programmatically call the admin API to then bind the data to the table?

Comment: You have to do it through scripts.

Comment: @Morfinismo I've added a script to the app and pasted the "ListAllGroups" sample code I found here https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/advanced/adminSDK.gs, but I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: AdminDirectory is not defined
at page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({ (NewScript:8)". Do I have to enable google API scripts in order for my app to be able to talk to the admin API?

Comment: You are probably using that code in the client script and not in the server script. You have to use it in the server scripting.

Comment: @Morfinismo please see my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already enabled the Admin Directory API when using the directory model, all you have to do now is to call the sample code from the server script. In a server script, add the sample code:

```
function listAllGroups() {
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
      domain: 'example.com',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var groups = page.groups;
    if (groups) {
      for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        var group = groups[i];
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', group.name, group.email);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No groups found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Then you can simply call the server script by using the following in the client scripting:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response){
    console.log(response);
}).withFailureHandler(function(err){
    console.log(err);
}).listAllGroups();
```

You can check the reference **[here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/client#call_a_server_script)**. I hope this helps!

Comment: I've added the code snippet to my client and server scripts. However, I'm still getting an error "GoogleJsonResponseException: Not Authorized to access this resource/api at listAllGroups " which seems permission related. Do I have to enable the Admin API at a different level?

Comment: @jorgeAChacon In this case you don't have permission to read groups via api. Make sure you are using a admin user with those permissions. A Super Admin user should give no problem.